# Overheating of wifi M.2 card AC 9260

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, debian, hardware-failure, pci-express

I upgraded a wifi card to Intel AC 9260 ([link](https://wikidevi.wi-cat.ru/index.php/Intel_Dual_Band_Wireless-AC_9260_(9260NGW))) on Dell Latitude E5400 which runs on Debian testing (5.2.0-3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.2.17-1 (2019-09-26) x86_64). Everything works excellent but when I make some greater bandwidth (over 10MB/s) I can see the temperature rise to quite risky values (about 97 °C according to sensors commands).

```
$sensors
iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:    

+97.0°C
```

How much shall I worry about it? Is there any sensible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hot radios are often caused by an inefficient connection of antenna to transceiver. Ideally, we want to send all the transmission power from the transceiver (your WiFi card) through the antennas into the atmosphere.

If there's a mismatch or poor connection caused by kinked or broken antennas, reflections surrounding both sides of an antenna, or a poor connection to the WiFi card, power bounces back and gets the card hot. Also, if you increase the bandwidth, you're increasing the power transmitted.

Open up the lid behind the screen of your laptop to check for kinks in the cable or if the antenna wires have fallen down to lie between metal or foil.

Open up the WiFi card location and make sure both antenna wires are firmly connected.

If none of those appear to be a problem, clean the antenna contacts with isopropyl alcohol, take a Pink Pearl type eraser to the contacts to scrub off any oxidation, reclean with alcohol, and test again.

Make sure there's nothing fallen out of place (like a piece of paper or sticker) to block airflow around the WiFi assembly.

If all else fails, try to decrease transmission power instead.

Comment: There were antennas with older UFL connector in the laptop. I used UFL to MHF4 cable adapters so didn't have to buy new antennas. I suspect those adapters can be low quality and thus as you say they impede the transmission. Thanks a lot for a tip. I'll check it out. https://imgur.com/2evwX0l